# Trouble with time dependant random number seed on SLURM

Tags: c++, linux

So I work as a summer student researcher and I have a c++ code which runs simulations that requires random numbers. I have to run a mass amount of these codes using a slurm scheduler. Right now my code takes in the time as the seed for the random number generator in my c++ code. But if I run multiple job submissions of the same code at the same time since they require so much time and resources to run each time they get put in the queue and typically the will all start around the same time or in larger groups which means that each run will have the same time for the seed of the random number generator which is a problem as each run needs to be unique(or as close as possible with this method) is there a way to get each run to input a unique seed for each run.
I am currently trying to run each job in its own folder within the main folder of the batch run and give each its own input file with a random number that was made from a script but this seems way to inefficient.

Comment: Use [std::random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)` and seed with `std::random_device`.

Comment: How would this make each run uniquely random and not just make every run identical again by following the same set of pseudo random numbers?

Comment: Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy. It's supposed to be non-deterministic (although MingGW apparently doesn't fullfill that).

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use time to seed. It's usually better to use [std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) that produces non-deterministic random numbers from an entropy pool.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> dist20(1, 20);
    auto d20 = [&](){ return dist20(generator); };

    // generate 100 random numbers [1,20]
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
        std::cout << d20() << "\n";
}
```

However, in some implementations of `std::random_device` will incorrectly report an entropy of 0 even though the entropy pool is not empty. On linux you can try to extract from the pool directly using `getrandom()` and use that for seeding. This is one way of doing it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

// https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/random.cpp#L175
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/random.h>

std::random_device::result_type backup_seed() {
    std::random_device::result_type seed;
    if(getrandom(&seed, sizeof(seed), 0) == sizeof(seed)) errno = 0;
    return seed;
}

std::random_device::result_type seed() {
    errno = EAGAIN;
    static thread_local std::random_device rd;
    if(rd.entropy()) return rd();
    return backup_seed();
}

int main() {
    std::mt19937 generator(seed());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> dist20(1, 20);
    auto d20 = [&]() { return dist20(generator); };

    // generate 100 random numbers [1,20]
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) std::cout << d20() << "\n";
}
```

Note that you should only use `getrandom()` to extract numbers for seeding or you risk having a very slow random number generator when/if you deplete the entropy pool.

Comment: when I look at the entropy (rd.entropy()) I get a value of 0 constantly

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I think clang may have a bug making it report 0 when it isn't 0.